# iPad session error?

Tags: php, facebook, session

I have the following code which works perfectly on browsers but not on the [iPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad), and I suspect [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) too although haven't tested it:

```
require '/home/****/php_/lib/fb_libs/facebook.php';
require '/home/****/php_/lib/fb_libs/fbconfig.php';

session_start();

$facebook = $_SESSION['facebook'];
$userdata = $_SESSION['userdata'];

echo "Your email address is ".$userdata['email']."<br /><br />";

echo "Your name is ".$userdata['name']."<br /><br />";

echo "Your Facebook ID is ".$userdata['id']."<br /><br />"; die;
```

The iPad simply does not return the variables `$userdata[*]`.

Is there something different I should know about RE iPad? I am tearing my hair out here with this.

This is the result on a browser:

```
Your email address is darren@email.com

Your name is Darren Sweeney

Your Facebook ID is 123456789
```

On iPad

```
Your email address is

Your name is

Your Facebook ID is
```

Comment: well how do you set $_SESSION['userdata']. Is the session valid?

Comment: @Topener amended question, it was wrong as i was testing things out but its in correct order now.

Comment: so the problem still remains?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Yes, still the same

Comment: do var_dump($userdata); and for $facebook.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar var_dump produces all data on browser and NULL on Ipad

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your iPad's Safari is configured to accept all cookies.

Your app sits in Facebook's iFrame, which in turn makes your hosting of the app a 3rd-party page. So, you gotta enable 3rd-party cookies on the browser.
I had an issue with this as well creating a Facebook app.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` should be defined before using any session variable. Hence place it on the top:

```
session_start();
$facebook = $_SESSION['facebook'];
$userdata = $_SESSION['userdata'];
```

This is causing the problem for you.

Comment: No, just amended question, same with it set like you say